# Go channel not receiving/printing last value sent to channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Here's a piece of code which outputs a list of integers as pushed to a channel. Else a select checks and prints necessary timeout message.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    c := make(chan int)

    go readFromChannel(c, time.After(time.Duration(2)*time.Second))
//  time.Sleep(time.Duration(5) * time.Second) //Talking about uncommenting this line
    c <- 10
    c <- 20
    c <- 30
    c <- 40
    c <- 50
    wg.Wait()
}

func readFromChannel(c chan int, ti <-chan time.Time) {
    defer wg.Done()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case x := <-c:
                fmt.Println("Read", x)
            case t :=<-ti:
                fmt.Println("TIMED OUT with "+t.String())
            }
        }
    }()

}
```

Also here's the playground link for the same : https://play.golang.org/p/4hNWze4Pfwr
This code outputs list of integer like

```
Read 10
Read 20
Read 30
Read 40
Read 50
```

But when I un-comment the line that make the main routine go to sleep for 5 sec(mentioned in the code as comment/line number 16), output changes to :

```
TIMED OUT with 2009-11-10 23:00:02 +0000 UTC m=+2.000000001
Read 10
Read 20
Read 30
Read 40
```

I want to understand why the last `Read 50` is not being printed in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `wg.Done()` is in the wrong place.  It must be *in your goroutine*, but you're executing it before the goroutine even starts, so your program is liable to exit before doing any work.

Change this:

```
defer wg.Done()
go func() {
```

to this:

```
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
```

Of course then you'll have an infinitely running goroutine, because your `for` loop has no exit condition. You'll need to add one, probably by checking for the channel closing:

```
        select {
        case x, ok := <-c:
            if !ok { // channel was closed
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("Read", x)
        case t :=<-ti:
            fmt.Println("TIMED OUT with "+t.String())
        }
```

Then tell your main go routine to close the channel when it's done:

```
c <- 40
c <- 50
close(c)  // We're done, so tell the goroutine to finish up
wg.Wait() // But wait until it's done
```

Comment: Great! Works fine. One more question. Using your code, I changed `if !ok {return}` to `if ok {fmt.Println("Read", x)}`. And it still worked fine. What broke the loop here? Is there any BTS processing in `select` when a channel is closed?

Comment: What breaks the loop in that case, is the program exiting.